# Trying to do an fetch_assoc inside an fetch_assoc PHP, MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

I have a problem in the second while, only enter one time inside. The second loop for the first while, the second while doesn't do nothing.
The first iteration of first while the code run successfully, but on the second iteration he doens't enter on the while inside.

```
    while($first = $firstSurvey->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $counterR1 = 0;
        $counterR2 = 0;
        $counterR3 = 0;
        $counterR4 = 0;
        $counterR5 = 0;
        $conta = 2;
        if(empty($first["resposta1"])) { 
    ?>
          <p style="margin-top: 1rem;margin-bottom: 0px;"><b><?php echo $first['id']; ?>. <?php echo $first['pergunta']; ?></b></p>
          
<?php   
    } else {
        while($respostas = $sqlRespostas->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $conta;

            switch ($respostas['resposta' . $conta]) {
                case $first['resposta1']:
                    $counterR1++;
                    break;
          
                case $first['resposta2']:
                    $counterR2++;
                    break;
    
                case $first['resposta3']:
                    $counterR3++;
                    break;
    
                case $first['resposta4']:
                    $counterR4++;
                    break;
    
                case $first['resposta5']:
                    $counterR5++;
                    break;
         
                default:
                    break;
            }
            $total++;
        }
        $conta++;
        $progress1 = ($counterR1 * 100) / $total;
        $progress2 = ($counterR2 * 100) / $total;
        $progress3 = ($counterR3 * 100) / $total;
        $progress4 = ($counterR4 * 100) / $total;
        $progress5 = ($counterR5 * 100) / $total;
    } 
}   
?>
```

Comment: You can only fetch results once from a result set. Why do you think the `while` ever stops in the first place?

Comment: Because you have consumed all the `$sqlRespostas` resultset the first time you enter the inner loop

Comment: I would suggest you read that result set into an array, then you can process it as many times as you like

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you so much, i save the result in an array, and it solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem saving the results of second while in a array like this

```
$arrayRespostas = array();
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlRespostas))
{
    $arrayRespostas[] = $result;
}
```

And substituted this

```
while($respostas = $sqlRespostas->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Into this

```
foreach ( $arrayRespostas as $respostas) {
```

Many thanks to RiggsFolly